# Transmit Data over PoE using PoE+ Hat Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: poe

Hello I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 (Rpi4) as a WiFi to Ethernet converter. I programmed the Rpi4 to act as a DHCP server and this setup is working fine in converting WiFi to Ethernet (transmitting data, I can see the ethernet port LEDs flashing). I wanted to power this Rpi4 over PoE, so I got the PoE+ hat and when I attached it and connected it to the PoE+ injector, I was able to power the Rpi4 but I didn't get any transmitted data over ethernet (neither of the ethernet port LEDs are on), and I can't figure out why.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do a Warranty claim.

Comment: It is most likely that your adapter does not have Gigabit Ethernet support. Buy a suitable adapter or downgrade your Ethernet to 100MHz. Your question lacks details

Comment: What info or details do you need and I can edit my question? How can I downgrade my Ethernet?

Comment: Try to power the Raspberry Pi 4 using a traditional power supply (without the PoE+ Hat). See if the Ethernet connection works as expected. If it does, then the problem might be related to the PoE+ Hat or its configuration.

Comment: Does networking work if you connect the Pi to your (unspecified) device without the HAT? Before fiddling with anything you should do some checks to see what you have. Try ONE step at a time.

Comment: Yes, it does without the HAT, and I tried your suggestion of downgrading my Ethernet to 100MHz and it worked.